# Positioning an iframe

Tags: css, iframe, html

I need to load a page with an iframe in a way that its header is hidden. I tried the following but for some reason it isn't working:

```
<div style="width:945px; height:600px; overflow:hidden;"> 
    <iframe src="innerpage.html" 
        frameborder="0" 
        height="700" 
        scrolling="no" 
        width="945"  
        style="top:-100px" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What meder said is true, but it could also be that your style wouldn't do anything. You'll need to set `position: absolute` or `position: static` in order for `top` to have any impact.

This will just move the whole iframe up though, not the content within the iframe.

Comment: the style would apply to the iframe, not the contents of the iframe.

Comment: unless i'm mistaken in that he wants to actually position *the* iframe, not the contents.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't working because you can't style the inside of an iframe from the parent, without accessing the document inside whether from the parent's javascript, or a stylesheet inside the iframe assuming said iframe is on the same domain as yours.